# Fixing HTML Tags within XML files using Python

Tags: python, html, xml, tags

I have been given .htm files that are structured in XML format and have HTML tags within them. The issue is that alot of these HTML tags along the way have been converted. For example & lt; has been converted to <, & amp; has been converted to & etc. Is there a python module that is able fix these HTML entities kindof like: [HTML Corrector](https://www.htmlcorrector.com/)

For example:

```
<Employee>
  <name> Adam</name
  <age> > 24 </age>
  <Nicknames> A & B </Nicknames>
</Employee>
```

In this above example, the > in age would be converted to '& gt;' and the & would converted to '& amp;'

Desired Result:

```
<Employee>
  <name> Adam</name
  <age> &gt; 24 </age>
  <Nicknames> A &amp; B </Nicknames>
</Employee>
```

Comment: `& amp;` ,  `& gt` .... there should not be any space

Comment: You can use `html.unescape(html_string)`

Comment: @EL-AJIOussama I've tried that- but inorder to do that I would need to parse only the HTML content within the XML. And no XML dom parser would parse an invalid XML like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML is well-formed, you can just convert to a BeautifulSoup object (from [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)) and the inner text of each tag will be escaped:

```
my_html = \
"""<Employee>
<name> Adam</name>
<age> > 24 </age>
<Nicknames> A & B </Nicknames>
</Employee>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html)
print(soup)
```

Outputs:

```
<employee>
<name> Adam</name>
<age> &gt; 24 </age>
<nicknames> A &amp; B </nicknames>
</employee>
```

Not sure if this was intentional, but the exact example you provided includes a broken tag, `</name` without the closing `>`. You'd need to fix this which is tricker—you could maybe use a regular expression. This gets the correct output for your example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_html = \
"""<Employee>
<name> Adam</name
<age> > 24 </age>
<Nicknames> A & B </Nicknames>
</Employee>"""

my_html = re.sub(r"</([^>]*)(\s)", r"<\1>\2", my_html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html)
print(soup)
```